# python turtle graphics turtle click, but ValueError: -142.0 is not in list

Tags: python, onclick, turtle-graphics

If I click on each turtle, I want it to function separately. But when I clicked on the turtle, they say:'ValueError: -142.0 is not in list.'
I want to click the turtle but it returns the location of the mouse. What should I do?

```
import turtle as t
import random

tt=[]
num=[]

def leftclick(self,x):
    if num[tt.index(self)]==0:
        self.hideturtle()
    else:
        self.color('red')

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        tt.append(t.Turtle())
        tt[i*10+j].speed(0)
        tt[i*10+j].goto(-260+j*55,260-i*55)
        num.append(random.choice([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]))
        tt[i*10+j].onclick(leftclick)
```

onclilck(leftclick)
Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Did you look up the parameters to the [`onclick` callback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onclick)? "`fun` – a function with two arguments which will be called with the coordinates of the clicked point on the canvas", in other words, `x` and `y`, not `self` and `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that you pass to `onclick()` has a predefined *signature* (arguments and return value) that you can't change to match your needs.  However, we can wrap it (via `lambda` or the `partial()` routine) to get the behavior we want:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice
from functools import partial

FREQUENCY = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

turtles = []
numbers = []

def leftclick(self, x, y):
    if numbers[turtles.index(self)] == 0:
        self.hideturtle()
    else:
        self.color('red')

screen = Screen()

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        turtle = Turtle()
        turtle.speed('fastest')
        turtle.goto(-260 + j*55, 260 - i*55)
        turtle.onclick(partial(leftclick, turtle))

        turtles.append(turtle)
        numbers.append(choice(FREQUENCY))

screen.mainloop()
```